# How to checkout the latest commit with Github Actions?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, git-checkout, github-actions

I created a new Rust project and decided, I'll give [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) a try to run automated builds and tests on each pull request:

```
name: Rust
on: [pull_request]
```

It took me a while to notice that by default, Github Actions does *not* checkout my code at all and the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` is just empty. So, I tried manually cloning the repository. Doing something like this:

```sh
REPO=/tmp/path/to/repository
git clone https://github.com/myself/mycode.git $REPO
```

But this just checks out whatever is on the default branch. So, I investigated checking out `$GITHUB_SHA` which turns out to be something that is unknown to my repository. And the same is true for `$GITHUB_REF` which is just empty.

At this point I am clueless, about what I am doing. My initial assumption was that a job that is literally configured to run `on: [pull request]` should have exactly that code but it does not manage to checkout and prepare the it.

I also investigated the provided [Checkout Actions](https://github.com/actions/checkout):

> This action checks out your repository to `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, so that your workflow can access the contents of your repository.
>
> By default, this is equivalent to running `git fetch` and `git checkout $GITHUB_SHA`, so that you'll always have your repo contents at the version that triggered the workflow.
>   See [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/events-that-trigger-workflows) to learn what `$GITHUB_SHA` is for different kinds of events.

But as I said before, the `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` is entirely empty, and a `git fetch` will just tell you that there is no git repository.

Here's such an [example failure](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/runs/228669159):

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
fatal: reference is not a tree: d76745134ae45905e4a0ab8d27c92f1e2544bdc1
##[error]Process completed with exit code 128.
```

What is the `$GITHUB_SHA` if it's unknown to my repository? Do I completely misunderstand Github Actions? How to checkout the latest commit with Github Actions, i.e., on a pull request?

Here's the [chronology of my failures](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/pull/15).

Comment: try adding `- uses: actions/checkout@v1` as the first step in your steps. It's an [official action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) provided by github and is the recommended way of setting up your project in CI/CD workflows.

Comment: Oh, I skimmed your post and didn't notice that you were aware of the action. Did you actually try it out?

Comment: Yes, check [this job](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/runs/229641925) or [that one](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/pull/15/checks?check_run_id=229648240), the checkout actions does not clone but download a tarball which is not available for every `$GITHUB_SHA` ...

Comment: You shouldn't put the github sha anywhere, the version for that action is just `v1`. Can you test the action with the exact string that I gave in my first comment?

Comment: That's actually part of the answer. It works. The `$GITHUB_SHA` is still incorrect but I am now at least [where I want to be](https://github.com/dothereum/dothereum/pull/15/checks?check_run_id=229653238): `HEAD detached at pull/15/merge`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do in that step. Why do you want to check out some commit, or is that just an artifact? Or rather, what's currently missing to solve your problem?

Comment: No, this is exactly the answer actually. I wasn't aware that I have to checkout the checkout actions `@v1` and that the `$GITHUB_SHA` is coming from a merge commit `HEAD is now at fffe487 Merge 5a38ed7f21833af6747f0dc7d58822f75aea77f7 into aa4c897113df504e876a57d7e79505f5656225d3` (which is not necessary IMO. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [official action](https://github.com/actions/checkout) that handles checkout. The `github-actions`' way of doing things takes some getting used to since it's a project management suite that doesn't solely cater to CI/CD needs.

So, some things are bound to be a bit strange or cumbersome, most of all because the documentation on all this isn't very mature yet - but hey, it's a beta for a reason.

The basic usage of this action is:

- find the `steps` section where you would want to have your current commit checked out
- add the action before writing a step that relies on the code to be there, usually at the very top
- decide which version **of the action** you want to use, the tutorials will often have `@master`, but it's a little safer to name the current latest version - in this case `@v1`
- enjoy your working workflow

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      # may or may not have a name, it's quite self-descriptive
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      # run steps that rely on the code in the commit that was pushed
      - name: test code
        steps: ...
      - name: build package
        steps: ...
```